# Is there any preprocessing technique for clustering that removes 'isolated' points?

Tags: cluster-analysis

So I expect noisy data for clustering. There's no pre-assumed number of clusters and I don't want the isolated noise points to result in smaller clusters. How can I remove them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms such as DBSCAN and k-means-- that can handle such isolated points, without having to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can handle this.

1. The way that you asked about - removing the noise points - outliers. In order to do that you must detect the outliers. For that, you could compute [Local Outlier Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor) using the `lof` function in the package Rlof.
2. Use a clustering algorithm that specifically identifies noise. The one that I would recommend is [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). You can get an R implementation of that algorithm in the package called dbscan.